# Work out how old a user was on the 1st January using Twig and Symfony2

Tags: date, symfony, twig

I'm building a system where a user's date of birth, as well as how old that user would have been on the 1st January of the year is displayed. So it would display the date of birth of Joe Bloggs as `10th October 1987`, and then how old that person was on the 1st January of the current year (which would be `25` in this case).

Because the users will be displayed on a list, along with their full name and email address, I want to be able to display their age as part of this information using Twig. However, I can't seem to fathom how to achieve this.

Comment: if you don't know how to calculate the age, just take the current year and substract the birth year from it. So it would be something like this:      $age = date('y') - $birthYear;

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think that you need to add the appropriate [Twig Filter](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/advanced.html#filters) in order to turn a given Date of Birth into a specific age.

Take a look at [Extending Twig](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/advanced.html) part of the documentation, you may notice that [adding a new filter](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/advanced.html#filters) is so trivial.

**How to ...**

1 - add a custom twig extension class that extends `\Twig_Extension`

```
class customExtension extends \Twig_Extension {
```

2 - Add the appropriate filter by overriding `getFilters()` method

```
   public function getFilters() {
        return array(
            'age' => new \Twig_Filter_Method($this, 'getAge'),
        );
    }
```

3 - Add some logic to get the age of a given Date of Birth

```
public function getAge($date) 
{
    if (!$date instanceof \DateTime) {
        // turn $date into a valid \DateTime object or let return
        return null;
    }

    $referenceDate = date('01-01-Y');
    $referenceDateTimeObject = new \DateTime($referenceDate);

    $diff = $referenceDateTimeObject->diff($date);

    return $diff->y;
}
```

Then, call your filter as follow,

```
{{ yourDateOfBirthInstance | age }}
```

Comment: I've followed and had some success, basically I've created the custom filter and used the code provided by @Amal Murali. However, Twig doesn't seem to support the use of "DateTime"?

Comment: Then, check this [fully implemented example](https://github.com/sgomez/UcoTwigExtensionsBundle/blob/master/Twig/DateExtension.php) when \DateTime objects are used. I also updated my answer.

Answer (score 4):

By creating a twig extension SimpleFilter you will be able to do:{{ app.user.birthday|age }}

```
<?php

// src/You/YourBundle/Twig/AgeExtension.php

namespace You\YourBundle\Twig;

class AgeExtension extends \Twig_Extension
{

    public function getFilters()
    {
        return array(
            new \Twig_SimpleFilter('age', array($this, 'ageCalculate')),
        );
    }

    public function ageCalculate(\DateTime $bithdayDate)
    {
        $now = new \DateTime();
        $interval = $now->diff($bithdayDate);

        return $interval->y;
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'age_extension';
    }
}
```

Register your extension

```
# src/You/YourBundle/Resources/config/services.yml

You\YourBundle\Twig\AgeExtension:
    class: You\YourBundle\Twig\AgeExtension
    tags:
        - { name: twig.extension }
```

To use it :

```
{{ user.birthday|age }}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [`DateTime`](http://php.net/datetime) class:

```
$januaryDate = date('01-m-Y');
$sDateBirth = '10th October 1987'; 

$oDateNow = new DateTime($januaryDate);
$oDateBirth = new DateTime($sDateBirth);
$oDateInterval = $oDateNow->diff($oDateBirth);
echo $oDateInterval->y;
```

Output:

```
25
```